# Combining multiple methods into one

Tags: ruby, methods, lambda, proc

I am wondering if there was a way to combine multiple methods into one using `Proc.new`, `lambda`, or another method.

Also there is something wrong with my code below.

```
def multiples(n,p)
  (n..p).each do |e|
  puts e if e%2 == 0 or e%3 == 0
  end
end

def summing(n)
  sum = 0
  n.each { |x| puts sum+=x }
end
```

It provides the correct answer when I test them individually like `multiples(2,43)` or `summing([2,6,5,4])`, but when I combine the two like `summing(multiples(0,10))`, I get the wrong answer.

If somebody could help me, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The below should work..

```
def multiples(n,p)
  (n..p).map do |e|
    e if e%2 == 0 or e%3 == 0
  end.compact
end

def summing(n)
  sum = 0
  n.each { |x| p sum+=x }
end

summing(multiples(0,10))
# >> 0
# >> 2
# >> 5
# >> 9
# >> 15
# >> 23
# >> 32
# >> 42
```

`Array#each` will not help you,for your task,as it returns the receiver when finished.

Answer (score 0):

Jamaal,

You want `summing` to return `sum` (rather than `n`), so you need `sum` at the end:

```
   def summing(n)
     sum = 0
     n.each { |x| puts sum += x}
     sum
   end
```